# get_avatar_url() how to reset the default image

Tags: avatar

I use the get_avatar_url() to retrieve the default gravatar image of an user.

```
get_avatar_url( $user_id );
```

In case there is non I will provide and default using the arguments array.

```
$arg = array (
'default' => get_home_url() . '/wp-content/uploads/.../profile_image_0.jpg',
);

$avatar = get_avatar_url( $user_id , $arg );
```

This is working fine until I need to replace the image. The problem is that the "https://i1.wp.com" service is caching the image.

So the question is how to reset or exchange the image without changing the filename?

Answer (score 0):

Paste below code in function.php file

```
function theme_custom_avatar_url($url, $idOrEmail, $args){

    return get_home_url() . '/wp-content/uploads/.../profile_image_0.jpg';
}
add_filter('get_avatar_url', 'theme_custom_avatar_url', 10, 3);
```

Comment: This will be an general OVERRIDE for the URL
I need to override it just for this Users which do not have an gravatar Image